# jQuery removeClass on iFrame button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I wrote some code to `addClass` to elements to open an iFrame imported by Shopify on WordPress and it works.
But now, I want to close the iFrame by removing the class on my website element.
I've tried a lot of things but it dosen't work

Here is my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.cart-button').click(function() {
            $('.shopify-buy-cart-wrapper').addClass('is-active is-visible');
            $('.shopify-buy-cart-wrapper iframe').addClass('is-block');
            return false;
        });
        //$("iframe").contents().find("button .shopify-buy__btn--close").click(function(){
        $('.shopify-buy__btn--close').click(function() {
            $('.shopify-buy-cart-wrapper').removeClass('is-active is-visible');
            $('.shopify-buy-cart-wrapper iframe').removeClass('is-block');
        }); 
    });
});
```

Open cart is working, but now I want to close the cart

Comment: I don't get your point. Your code works fine. See https://jsfiddle.net/af96t503/

Comment: @RezaSaadati the close button is generated with the iframe, looks like my code doesn't know where to pick the click action

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So the close button is within your iframe and your goal is to close that iframe when that button has been clicked. Right?

Comment: @RezaSaadati Yes, I use Shopify Buy Button, and the close button is in the iFrame, so I try to reach it to remove previous classes when the button has been clicked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove multiple classes with jQuery `removeClass()` you have to pass them as an array, not as a string.

Also, any event listener should be attached only **after** the element has been inserted in the DOM. If you define the event listener but the element is created afterwards, it won't work.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work